# Jquery form submit handler not being invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble submitting this form. Basically nothing happens and there are no errors in the Javascript console.

The form id is advancedSearchForm. I have other Jquery functions working on the page so there cannot be any conflict with $.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function submitForm() {
    $("#advancedSearchForm").submit(function(){
          alert("Submitted");
    });
}
bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function()
{
    //var form = document.getElementById('advancedSearchForm');
    //alert(form);
    //form.submit();
    submitForm();
    alert('You are going back!');
};

</script>
<form id="advancedSearchForm" action="someUrl">
..........
</form>
```

As you can see, I have tried various approaches including the document.getElementById submit but it hasn't fired.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $("#advancedSearchForm").submit(function() {
        alert("Submitted");
    });
});


bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function() {
    $("#advancedSearchForm").submit();
    alert('You are going back!');
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the script to

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $("#advancedSearchForm").submit(function(){
          alert("Submitted");
    });

bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function()
{
    var form = document.getElementById('advancedSearchForm');
    //alert(form);
    form.submit();
    alert('You are going back!');
};

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun but that didn't work. I would have expected the Submitted alert to have come up but it didn't

Comment: You'd also need to either move the script to after the form or bind the submit handler from within a document ready (or onload) handler. (Otherwise `$("#advancedSearchForm")` finds no form element because it hasn't been parsed yet.)